# How could I make example for sigma type in Coq?

Tags: coq

For that type:

```
Record Version := mkVersion { 
  major  : nat; 
  minor  : nat; 
  branch : {b:nat| b > 0 /\ b <= 9};
  hotfix : {h:nat| h > 0 /\ h < 8} 
}.
```

I'm trying to make an example:

```
Example ex1 := mkVersion 3 2 (exist _ 5) (exist _ 5).
```

And it failed with:

> The term "exist ?P 5" has type  "?P 5 -> {x : nat | ?P x}" while it is
>   expected to have type  "{b : nat | b > 0 /\ b <= 9}".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it fails is that you need not only provide a witness (`b` and `h` in this case) but also a proof that the corresponding condition holds for the provided witness.

I would switch to booleans to make my life easier, because this allows proof by computation, which is basically what `eq_refl` does in the snippet below:

```
From Coq Require Import Bool Arith.

Coercion is_true : bool >-> Sortclass.

Record Version := mkVersion {
  major  : nat;
  minor  : nat;
  branch : {b:nat| (0 <? b) && (b <=? 9)};
  hotfix : {h:nat| (0 <? h) && (h <? 8)}
}.

Example ex1 := mkVersion 3 2 (exist _ 5 eq_refl) (exist _ 5 eq_refl).
```

We could introduce a notation allowing a nicer representation of literals:

```
Notation "<| M ',' m ',' b '~' h |>" :=
  (mkVersion M m (exist _ b eq_refl) (exist _ h eq_refl)).

Example ex2 := <| 3,2,5~5 |>.
```

If there is a need to add manual proofs then I'd suggest to use `Program` mechanism:

```
From Coq Require Import Program.

Program Definition ex3 b h (condb : b =? 5) (condh : h =? 1) :=
  mkVersion 3 2 (exist _ b _) (exist _ h _).
Next Obligation.
  now unfold is_true in * |-; rewrite Nat.eqb_eq in * |-; subst. Qed.
Next Obligation.
  now unfold is_true in * |-; rewrite Nat.eqb_eq in * |-; subst. Qed.
```

or `refine` tactic:

```
Definition ex3' b h (condb : b =? 5) (condh : h =? 1) : Version.
Proof.
  now refine (mkVersion 3 2 (exist _ b _) (exist _ h _));
  unfold is_true in * |-; rewrite Nat.eqb_eq in * |-; subst.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible to leave the proving of this to be in Proof. section after Example command?

Comment: @The_Ghost Sure, updated to illustrate some approaches.

Comment: Great! Thank you!